# Cordova can't open youtube:// deep link

Tags: cordova, hyperlink, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have cordova application. On start page I've put youtube deep link. But android can't open it. Could someone help me? On iOS it works properly.

Comment: I don't think android youtube app uses the youtube:// scheme

Comment: @Igor Hope this should help - https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Answer (score 2):

The following (using cordova-plugin-device and cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) works for me (code runs after "deviceready" event has fired, so plugins are available):

```
var btn = document.getElementById('youtubebutton');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (device.platform.toLowerCase() === 'android') {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('vnd.youtube:yI2oS2hoL0k', '_system');
  } else {
    // iOS
  }
);
```

Where `yI2oS2hoL0k` is the ID of the video I want to show in YouTube.

For iOS I noticed [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10868) in Cordova's JIRA that you might want to be aware of.  I was able to reproduce this and had issues opening a video in iOS with the latest YouTube as described in that ticket.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: This seems to be the safe way to open Universal Links too. 
I had the same issue with a Facebook Messenger link (http: //m.me/...) and only this worked.